# MySQL Insert data into column based on corresponding ID

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I have a table with product date records and CSV file with updated data for these date records. I need to create a query which updates these records based on the column ID (SKU) in this instance.

## DATABASE

*Relevant columns

```
entity_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, type_id, *sku*, has_options, required_options, *created_at*, updated_at, mf_guid

13366, 4, 4, simple, *18965*, 0, 0, *2015-05-18 20:08:27*, 2016-02-22 13:47:19, NULL
```

## CSV

```
sku, created_at
18965, 2016-02-15 16:00:58
```

The logic I am looking for here is:

```
UPDATE '2016-02-15 16:00:58' IF 'sku' = 'sku'
```

As I have over 50k records, I've used EmEdiotr to insert this query to every row.

```
UPDATE 'catalog_product_entity' SET created_at="2016-02-15 16:00:58" WHERE sku = '18965';
```

Comment: Aren't you talking about updating, not inserting? Did you google how to update in mysql?

Comment: It is UPDATE as you have suggested. I am only stating the estimated logic, as I have looked into MySQL queries and can not find anything relevant. It is probably something relatively easy but I lack knowledge in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
    `UPDATE tablename SET created_at="2016-02-15 16:00:58" WHERE sku = '18965';`

Answer (score 0):

In case you import the CSV file as a table into your database you could use:

```
UPDATE table1.table_name
SET table1.created_at = csvtable.created_at 
FROM table1  INNER JOIN csvtable ON table1.sku = csvtable.sku
```

Where `csvtable` is the table name of the imported CSV table and `table1` is the first table you talk about.

This query sets the created value to the created value from the `csvtable` for **every** corresponding `sku` entry.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Query should be like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET created_at = '2016-02-15 16:00:58'
WHERE sku = 18965;
```